write data in excel sheet by using Flutter correctly
this code can write data in Excel Sheet but the problem is after open the modified sheet i fount all borders as in this figure below, which the borders are not completed and some colors are deleted .....etc, the provided code works well with an empty excel sheet
and this the sheet before adding any data:

and this the sheet after adding the data:

finally this is my code :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:excel/excel.dart' as ex;
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home:  HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String resultMessage = '';

  // List to hold the maps from all sheets
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> sheetDataList = [];

  void processExcel() async {
    // Step 1: Upload the Excel file
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['xlsx'],
    );

    if (result != null) {
      File file = File(result.files.single.path!);

      // Step 2: Read the Excel file
      var bytes = file.readAsBytesSync();
      var excel = ex.Excel.decodeBytes(bytes);

      // Step 3: Loop through each sheet and process data
      for (var sheetName in excel.tables.keys) {
        var sheet = excel.tables[sheetName];

        if (sheet != null) {
          // Step 4: Write values to B6, B7, B8, B9 (you can change these values)
          sheet.cell(ex.CellIndex.indexByString("B6")).value =
              const ex.IntCellValue(100);
          sheet.cell(ex.CellIndex.indexByString("B7")).value =
              ex.TextCellValue('mm2');
          sheet.cell(ex.CellIndex.indexByString("B8")).value =
              const ex.DoubleCellValue(0.12);
          sheet.cell(ex.CellIndex.indexByString("B9")).value =
              const ex.IntCellValue(14);
        }
        //print(sheetDataList);
      }

      // Save the changes to a new file
      String newFilePath = file.path.replaceAll('.xlsx', '_modified.xlsx');
      File(newFilePath)
        ..createSync(recursive: true)
        ..writeAsBytesSync(excel.save()!);

      setState(() {
        resultMessage = "Excel file processed and saved as $newFilePath";
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        resultMessage = "No file selected.";
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Excel File Processor'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                processExcel();
              },
              child: const Text('Upload and Process Excel'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text(
              resultMessage,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                color: Colors.black87,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


My guess would be that that's a bug in the excel package.
